# How to graph a function that depends on another function

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, graph

I have a time-dependent function that draws a function (blue). y takes values 0 and 1. I need to draw a second function that at value 0 will use the function y = t0 + 2 * t + 100, and at value 1 will use the function y = t0 + 2 * t - 100. t0 is the value of the previous section of the function. (red)
[image]

The first function is obtained by traversing the list with intervals

```
t = np.linspace(0, 48, 1000)
y = np.zeros(len(t))

for v in values:
    # v is the interval in string type from v1 to v2
   y[((t >= v1) & (t <= v2))] = 1
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Is your red line meant to show the function you want to create? Because the formula you gave does not match the red line.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, it will be different. This is to visualize that the graph of the function (red) depends on the first function.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale and shift your first `y` to get a function that takes values -1 and 1 instead of 0 and 1. Then use `numpy.cumsum()` to get a function that increases when `y` is 1 and decreases when `y` is 0. Since you didn't provide code to fully reproduce the original `y` I have made up different initial data.

I called the scaled and shifted input `y2` and the result `z`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.zeros(160)
a[::10] = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
           0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

y = np.convolve(a, np.ones(10), mode='same')
y2 = y * 2 - 1
z = 0.02 * y2.cumsum() + 0.5

plt.plot(y)
plt.plot(y2)
plt.plot(z)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks, that's good! I may have given the example with functions( 2*t + 100, 2*t -100) incorrectly. There are different functions in my work, like 2 * t + 100 and -t^2 + t - 100. This will work if the functions are similar, but will it work with different functions?

Comment: @ilnarkz, I can't see any connection between that formula and the plot you produced. And you said that the actual formula will be "different" without saying anything about what it should actually be. So I ignored the formula and this answer has nothing to do with the formula.